# Force DataGridView Entire Row selection

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls

I have a datagridview showing in a UI with a list of devices. I want to force the user to select the entire row instead of a single cell... Googling for awhile it looks like there is no way to force row selection using the methods supplied for datagridview.

I did this, which works 50% of the time, some times, however it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].OwningRow.Index].Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is an easy way, just set the `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but this does not work all the time.
Once I fill the datagridview.datasource from a datatable, I can click all the rows in column[0] without it doing a full row select. Once I click outside of column[0] it then triggers.

Answer (score 2):

This code works fine to Select the whole row when the user clicks on any cell in the DGV:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
```

-Or- the simple ever way  is this (from project's "Properties"):

[image]